# Where should I implement my js for website

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hello all i have a bit of java script that I want to be applied to my index.html that looks like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

// Get scroll position
var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
// scroll value and opacity
opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
// opacity value 0% to 100%
$('.blurred-img').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

but I'm not sure where to put this I have made a new file called script.js with just that code and I reference it with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something in the script .js file or am I not refrencing properly? thanks

Comment: Where is this script tag inserted? If you call script.js before the full html is parsed, it won't find the queries elements.

Comment: Put the script just before the `</body>` tag and you can wrap it in `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: I put it in the head should I move it to the bottom?

Comment: Are you linking to the jQuery library? If not, you'll need to, and if so, you'll need to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){...code here...});`

Comment: If you're using JQuery, you could pop it into the document ready function to do get the same effect as enapupe and mdesdev are suggesting. If you're new to JS, JQuery is worth checking out.

Comment: im not currently linking to a librarry

Comment: im following this guide http://mattduvall.com/blog/medium-ux-blurry-scroll/ and im a total daft when it comes to js and jquery so please stick with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to defer the execution of your script until DOM-ready, to ensure that the elements you're including in your selector(s) exist at the time the script runs:

```
$(function() {
    // code here, runs when DOM is ready
});
```

As far as where, you can do what you're doing (and should), or put it in a `<script>` tag either in the `<head>` section of your page or conventionally right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've moved the script tag to just above the close body tag and wrapped the code around the function now i have this https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqewyksftemk4ky/script.js but it still doesnt work, anythoughts?

Comment: Any console errors? Did you add a reference to the jQuery library? http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: no I didnt refrence a library and some errors are there https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfigm7zzji77fsy/Screenshot%20from%202014-04-22%2019%3A13%3A11.png and the link was very useful

Comment: I'm not sure if you're misunderstanding but JavaScript != jQuery. jQuery is a helper library *written in* JavaScript, but it in itself does not constitute a language. For jQuery syntax to work, you **must** reference the jQuery library in your page.

Comment: how would I do that, Sorry for being a complete noob with js I'm really just trying to get it

Comment: Either (1) download an appropriate version of the jQuery JS library from the jQuery website and add it to your project, and then add a `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>` tag that points to it locally, or (2) don't download it yourself and instead point a `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>` tag at a CDN that serves it up freely, such as Google's (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery). Put the `<script>` tag in your `<head>` section *before* anything else that uses jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, make sure you include the script.js after including the jquery javascript.  also wrap your code in $(function(){}) to make sure it gets executed after the document is ready:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {

  // Get scroll position
  var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
  // scroll value and opacity
  opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
  // opacity value 0% to 100%
  $('.blurred-img').css('opacity', opacityVal);
  });
});
```